# Magento2.3: Product level validation in cart price rule is not working

Tags: magento2.3, cart, coupon, sku

I want to apply coupon for a particular product, so I have set the coupon is valid for SKU basis and selected the product which I wanted that the coupon has to apply. Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

However, the coupon code is applying for all the items in cart. Am I missing something? or Is this the bug in Magento 2.3?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please add same validation in Actions Tab and check

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal, Thanks, Its working fine after add validation in Actions and removed the validation in condition tab. So, one query here, what is the need of condition tab there? Also, you can send your reply as answer so that I will mark that as an answer and it will helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can add the same validation in the `Action` tab section for SKU
>   check

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this as answer and can you please tell me what is the difference between condition tab and actions tab? because there is a separate condition tab in Actions tab.